# IntelliJ autocomplete partially working

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just added some Java classes to my project in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3.  When I attempt to use autocomplete to add the elsewhere in the project, it does not find them.  It shows older classes, but not the new classes.  If I type out the class name, IntelliJ asks to import it and everything works.
What am I missing?  Why would if find some of my classes and not others?

Not the end of the world, but it is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just discovered the invalidate cache option.  This appears to have fixed the issue, by forcing a re-index.

For anyone else facing this problem, the option is under **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**